# How to say "Castile"

Tags: etymology, pronunciation

I am from Castile, NY. As far as I can tell it is the only town in the USA with that name. We say the name like /kae-STAI-ol/, but I am aware that many people pronounce it like /kae-STEEL/. The name of the town comes from the first settlers. The wife loved Spain so they took an Anglicized Castilla for a name. 
I am curious to hear what you all think about how to say this name. Who out there reads this and says it like me? What is your reason for doing so? For those who say it the other way, what is your reason?

Comment: A locale's name is pronounced as the locals wish. Why are you resisting?

Comment: I have no problems understanding why Worcester is pronounced the way it is pronounced as it follows the general patterns of syllable contraction in English, but it beats me why anyone would spell Spokane not the way it is pronounced.

Comment: There is an area of central London, just south of the Thames, known as *Elephant & Castle*. The origin of the name seems lost in the mists of time with a number of theories around. Some say there was once a pub there called *Infanta de Castilla*. (I don't speak Spanish but I assume it to mean *Castillian Child*). Anyway the Londoners of some century now passed could not get their tongues around the Spanish and spoke it as it sounded *Elephant & Castle*.

Comment: @WS2 *Infanta* means "Princess" and one Infanta de Castile was Constanza, who became John of Gaunt's second wife in 1371.

Comment: @AndrewLeach But if you read the Wiki entry for *Elephant & Castle* you will see that the authors are quite disparaging of this as being the origin of the name, notwithstanding several Spanish princesses who married into the English royal family.

Comment: They disparage Eleanor of Castile as being the source (*Infanta* wasn't used then), but make no mention of Constanza who **was** Infanta. I've added that to the Talk page. And these comments are getting off-topic!

Comment: @bib 'A locale's name is pronounced as the locals wish.' I don't usually follow that convention for 'Paris' or 'New York', and US citizens seem to have their own preference about say 'Durham'. As for 'Londres' ...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree that there are conventions of using the pronunciation in your own language when the other locale has a different language. However, even in those cases, there is a move to restore the home team's preferences (e.g., Beijing). The OP is talking about objecting to how his hometown-mates pronounce the name of his hometown. When I *am* in Paris, I pronounce it *Paree*.

Comment: @bib 'Who out there reads this and says it like me?' doesn't sound like he's restricting the discussion to his fellow Castillians. Which would make it even more off-topic. While we're on the subject (if off-topic), 'Shrewsbury' in the UK is pronounced 3 different ways _by its townspeople_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But there's only one way to say *Noo Yawk*

Comment: I've only just discovered that NYC's Houston is pronounced differently from Texas' (which itself may or may not suffer the yod-drop).

Answer (score 1):

Inhabitants of a number of other U.S. cities and towns with famous foreign counterparts have adopted pronunciations at variance with their more famous namesakes. For example:

> Cairo, Illinois (pronounced Kay-ro)
>
> Lima, Ohio (pronounced Lie-muh)
>
> Palestine, Texas (pronounced Pal-uh-steen)
>
> Weimar, Texas (pronounced Wie-mur)

The same goes for proper names that don't match the way they would originally have been pronounced:

> Baltimore, Maryland (pronounced [by some natives] Bol-mur)
>
> Lafayette, Louisiana (pronounced Laff-ee-yet)
>
> San Rafael, California (pronounced San Ruh-fell)

And foreign words that aren't pronounced at all faithfully to the original:

> Los Angeles, California (pronounced Loss An-juh-lus)
>
> Vallejo, California (pronounced Vuh-lay-ho)

The total number of such names in the United States is undoubtedly huge. But since the pronunciation of place names isn't based on fidelity to some idealized model, the only crucial thing is to pronounce them in ways that others can understand. If you want to blend in with your fellow townspeople, of course, it make sense to accommodate your pronunciation to their preferences (assuming that they generally agree on one pronunciation).

Comment: I should clarify that locals and I rhyme Castile with mile and tile. This question comes out of a discussion I recently had where my main point was that to say /ka-STEEL/ is to depart from the rules of English orthography and force a foreign pronunciation on the word. I know that in English we are sometimes sensitive to the origins of borrowed words. The problem here is that this name, as I've spelled it above, just seems so native to our language that I wonder why people who don't speak Spanish at all would opt for a Spanish-inspired pronunciation. My question is really a survey.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to confirm this, but I suspect that the reason is mostly historical. When the town was founded, the natives adopted a particular pronunciation. They gave it the ending *-ile*, and assumed it rhymes with *mile*. Over time, more words have been borrowed, and they have the *eel* pronunciation, but this name has resisted modification.

Traditions can be very strong, and locals probably enjoy correcting newcomers -- it engenders a sense of community. There's probably a similar reason for most of the examples that Sven Yargs gives in his answer.

The only one I disagree with is Baltimore -- that seems more like an accent than an official pronunciation. It's like Bostonians pronouncing Harvard as *Hah-vahd* -- they wouldn't correct someone who says *Har-vard*.